# xpath with multiple predicates equivalence

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I was told that the following are not the same:

```
a[1][@attr="foo"]
a[@attr="foo"][1]
```

Can someone explain why that is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of XPath expressions as defining a *result set*<sup>1</sup> - a set of nodes that fulfil all the requirements stated in the XPath expression. The predicates of XPath expressions (the parts inside `[]`) **either have no effect on the result set or they incrementally narrow it**.

Put another way, in the following expression:

```
//xyz[@abc="yes"]
```

`[@abc="yes"]` *reduces* the result set defined to the left of it, by `//xyz`.

Note that, as Michael Kay has suggested, all that is said below only applies to XPath expressions with at least one *positional* predicate. Positional predicates are either a number: `[1]` or evaluate to a number, or contain `position()` or `last()`.

If no positional predicate is present, the order of predicates in XPath expressions is not significant.

---

Consider the following simple input document:

```
<root>
  <a attr="other"/>
  <a attr="foo"/>
  <a attr="other"/>
  <a attr="foo"/>
</root>
```

As you can see, `a[@attr = 'foo']` is *not* the first child element of `root`. If we apply

```
//a[1]
```

to this document, this will of course result in

```
<a attr="other"/>
```

Now, crucially, if we add another predicate to the expression, like so:

```
//a[1][@attr="foo"]
```

Then, `[@attr="foo"]` can only influence the result set defined by `//a[1]` already. In this result set, there is no `a[@attr="foo"]` - and the final result is empty.

On the other hand, if we start out with

```
//a[@attr="foo"]
```

the result will be

```
<a attr="foo"/>
-----------------------
<a attr="foo"/>
```

and in this case, if we add a second predicate:

```
//a[@attr="foo"][1]
```

the second predicate `[1]` can narrow down the result set of `//a[@attr="foo"]` to only contain the *first* of those nodes.

---

If you know XSLT, you might find an XSLT (and XPath 2.0) proof of this helpful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <result1>
          <xsl:copy-of select="//a[1][@attr='foo']"/>
      </result1>
      <result2>
          <xsl:copy-of select="//a[@attr='foo'][1]"/>
      </result2>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

And the result will be

```
<result1/>
<result2>
   <a attr="foo"/>
</result2>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically speaking, only XPath 1.0 calls this result a *node-set*. In XPath 2.0, all sets have become true *sequences* of nodes.

Comment: Hum. Thanks for notifying me. I never thought the way you explained.

Comment: Just to add a note, the order of predicates is significant only if at least one of them is "positional". A predicate is positional if it evaluates to a number, or if it contains a call on either of the functions position() or last().

Comment: @MichaelKay You are right, that's an important note, I should have mentioned that! I'll edit my answer in a moment.

Comment: @MathiasMüller That's a pleasure of mine. :-)